# Where can I find documentation on formatting a date in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, date, datetime-format, date-format, time-format

I noticed that JavaScript's `new Date()` function is very smart in accepting dates in several formats.

```
Xmas95 = new Date("25 Dec, 1995 23:15:00")
Xmas95 = new Date("2009 06 12,12:52:39")
Xmas95 = new Date("20 09 2006,12:52:39")
```

I could not find documentation anywhere showing all the valid string formats while calling `new Date()` function.

This is for converting a string to a date. If we look at the opposite side, that is, converting a date object to a string, until now I was under the impression that JavaScript doesn't have a built-in API to format a date object into a string.

> **Editor's note:** The following approach is the asker's attempt that worked on a particular browser but does *not* work in general; **see the answers on this page** to see some actual solutions.

Today, I played with the `toString()` method on the date object and surprisingly it serves the purpose of formatting date to strings.

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');       //Returns "2009-06-29" in Internet Explorer, but not Firefox or Chrome
d1.toString('dddd, MMMM ,yyyy')  //Returns "Monday, June 29,2009" in Internet Explorer, but not Firefox or Chrome
```

Also here I couldn't find any documentation on all the ways we can format the date object into a string.

Where is the documentation which lists the format specifiers supported by the `Date()` object?

Comment: your examples don't actually work the way you think they do: http://jsfiddle.net/edelman/WDNVk/1/

Comment: Sorry, passing format strings in toString works in .NET, and it may work in Java, but as Jason pointed out, this doesn't actually work in Javascript.

Comment: Folks remember - questions, no matter how canonical, *need to remain questions*. Please refrain from any edit that turns this question into an answer, refine and maintain the _answers_ instead. Thanks :)

Comment: I used the code in this link http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx -- (date.toLocaleDateString("en-US"));

Comment: If future visitors to this page are confused by how most of the answers relate to the question, I suggest reading the [question revisions](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/1056728/revisions), especially (if different from above) [revision 15](http://stackoverflow.com/revisions/1056728/15) @[Eric Muyser](http://stackoverflow.com/users/119301) - I for one was confused by the lack of the invalid Date#toString usage.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Comment: While most of the answers are not really answers ("use library X" does not, of itself, help with documentation on formatting a date), it is quite reasonable to ask where ECMA-262 provides information on a specific task. That is what the answers should have addressed before mentioning other resources. It's difficult to see how any question relating to ECMA-262 can not link to an offsite resource since the specification is kept offsite.

Comment: I think that now the [EcmaScript Internationalization API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Intl) should be used to answer this question.

Something like that:


`let formattedDate = new Intl.DateTimeFormat('en-US').format(XMas95)`


It is currently the best solution.

Comment: @user66001 If future visitors are confused by this page, they should hit the 'back' button then go read [the documentation for Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date)...

Comment: @JasonC We must live in different worlds. In the one many people seem to inhabit, people like to take shortcuts, rather than read all knowledge about a subject before practicing it.

Comment: @user66001 I like shortcuts too; that's why I was annoyed by having to stop at this stupid page on the way, heh.

Comment: @JasonC We do live in different worlds. The amount of unrelated stuff I have to see before I chance upon a solution that address' my problem, without having to be intimately familiar with every language out there when I use a bunch of them, is phenomenal. I wish you luck preventing this.

Answer (score 1129, accepted):

I love *[10 ways to format time and date using JavaScript](https://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/10-ways-to-format-time-and-date-using-javascript)* and *[Working with Dates](http://www.elated.com/articles/working-with-dates/)*.

Basically, you have three methods and you have to combine the strings for yourself:

```
getDate() // Returns the date
getMonth() // Returns the month
getFullYear() // Returns the year
```

Example:

```js
var d = new Date();
var curr_date = d.getDate();
var curr_month = d.getMonth() + 1; //Months are zero based
var curr_year = d.getFullYear();
console.log(curr_date + "-" + curr_month + "-" + curr_year);
```

Comment: Both of these sites have restrictive licenses. So if you use the code (without permission), you'll be in violation. Momentjs (http://stackoverflow.com/a/10119138/278976) looks like a way better option and is MIT license.

Comment: @McKay the question specifically asked about string formats, a non-standard JS feature

Comment: @peller This answer answers the question "How do I format dates in javascript?" which is effectively the title of the question. In the body of the question he is quite mislead. And, to your point, this answer does not talk about string formatting using random non-standard or not mentioned libraries. But that part of the question was asked incorrectly, as the #1 comment on the question points out. So, this answers the real question, but not the format strings that don't actually exist.

Comment: @McKay; that wasn't the question.  I think you're either misunderstanding what the peller is asking or being obtuse in your reasoning.

Comment: @codeinthehole "Formatting dates in Javascript" is the question. "until now I was under the impression that JavaScript doesn't have a built-in API to format a date object into a string." but then talks about the behavior, that I believe he thinks is native in javascript. Without knowing which library he mistakenly references, I think the best guess is that he's asking the question, "How do I format dates in javascript?" and I don't think I'm taking wild leaps.

Comment: @codeinthehole if peller is referring to "non-standard js" implying that some browsers support such a feature, I'm not aware of any browsers supporting such a feature. I just tried it on Chrome, IE, FF, and Safari. Maybe Opera supports it?

Comment: @mcKay; Hi, thanks for explaining your reasoning.  I think the person who submitted the question is asking where he/she can find information about the various date formatting strings that are syntactically correct.  It seems the poster is aware of _how_ to format dates - but isn't aware of how the syntax for the formatting strings is derived.

Comment: @McKay specifically, the toString() signature taking a format string argument was a FF innovation, IIRC, and not standard JS. Firefox does not currently support this, I don't think any browser does anymore, which is why I felt it was important two years ago to discourage the user from doing this.  While JS libs may be the solution for this user, the question was very specific to the Date object in core JS and browser behavior in 2009.

Comment: @torvin even then you have to click through each page laboriously to go through all examples.

Comment: MM mean 01-12, not 1-12:
2013-04-17 => OK
2013-4-17 => BAD

Comment: Thanks a lot.I was wondering for the past 2 hours why I am getting difference of 1 for d.getMonth()

Comment: No part of this site can be duplicated in any form without
written permission from the Webmaster

Comment: important: don't forget to do `d.getMonth() + 1` because some moron programmer once decided dates should be zero based

Comment: I prefer the answer by chx007 referencing Moment.js, as it alleviates @Homer6 's concern about restrictive licenses and doing "technically-illegal" things.

Comment: @nathan No one can claim ownership of simple JavaScript statements. It is not technically illegal.

Answer (score 688):

**[Moment.js](http://momentjs.com)**

It is a (lightweight)* JavaScript date library for parsing, manipulating, and formatting dates.

```
var a = moment([2010, 1, 14, 15, 25, 50, 125]);
a.format("dddd, MMMM Do YYYY, h:mm:ss a"); // "Sunday, February 14th 2010, 3:25:50 pm"
a.format("ddd, hA");                       // "Sun, 3PM"
```

*(*) lightweight meaning 9.3KB minified + gzipped in the smallest possible setup (feb 2014)*

Comment: This also provides a decorator pattern around the Date object instead of monkey punching the core object, so you're less likely to get conflicts down the road.

Comment: I don't think I've ever come across a library in *any* programming language/environment that serves its purpose so perfectly. Also the docs are extensive and really, really good. Really happy to have found this because dates have been a pain to deal with in the past (though Datejs improved the situation somewhat for me).

Comment: FWIW, moment.min.js is currently at 14.3 KB.

Comment: I replaced Datejs with Moment recently.

Comment: Please stop abusing the word "lightweight". Even 5kb is ridiculously large for such functionality, and as per today that size has increased to 19kb.

Comment: As of this comment the moment.min.js file is at 8.9kb

Comment: @Pumbaa80 I disagree that "Even 5kb is ridiculously large for such functionality". [Have you seen the docs?](http://momentjs.com/docs/) It is an extremely useful library for dealing with dates in JS. I understand having a library greater than a couple of KBs for a single use of a basic format like "D/M/Y" can be a little overkill however differences of a few KBs is becoming negligible for then the ease of use the library provides. Maintainable code is a good thing for the sake of a few KBs. If it was +100KB minified, I would however agree.

Comment: "Lightweight" is relative.  Even 5KB wasn't lightweight by 1984's standards.  :/

Comment: @Tumerj arguing that it is useful does nothing to address the concern of being lightweight. The two are not related.

Comment: You can't make a jet plane more lightweight by removing the engine because it then becomes a glider and not a jet. Lightweight means something has only necessary functionality to perform a specified function. Ergo, this is a lightweight solution.

Comment: For those who are wondering about moment.js, see this simple fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/t5MuD/ it only shows a fraction of the power of moment. You can read a whole lot more on http://momentjs.com/docs/

Comment: @Pumbaa80 File size is irrelevant. While 'use datejs' is a solution to the OP's problem it does not actually answer the question. OP has learned nothing which is unfortunate because the actual answer is incredibly simple. SO is lousy with 'use jQuery' style answers.

Comment: Moment.js is by no means lightweight. In 2016, people were complaining about [tens/hundreds of kilobytes](https://github.com/moment/moment/issues/3376#issuecomment-260949065) added by the library, and a number of date picker libraries take pride in [*not*](https://github.com/flatpickr/flatpickr) depending on Moment.js.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.  Rather, SO should probably get rid of the "accept answer" functionality altogether

Answer (score 430):

If you are already using [jQuery UI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery_UI) in your project, you can use the built-in datepicker method for formatting your date object:

```
$.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date(2007, 1 - 1, 26));
```

However, the datepicker only formats dates, and cannot format times.

Have a look at [jQuery UI datepicker formatDate](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker/formatDate), the examples.

Comment: how to tell it to use local time or Zulu?

Comment: i prefer use this solution able to get the time without any library : new Date().toTimeString().match( /^([0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2})/ )[0] FYI

Comment: is there a way to do this. $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date("txtAdvDate".Val()); or some thing like that

Comment: @Pomster - what would make you think the string "txtAdvDate" would have a val method on it? Do you mean $('#txtAdvDate').val()? Assuming it fits one of the constructors (see here http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) then that would work just fine.

Comment: @Pomster - try using this: document.getElementById(id).value = $.datepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', new Date());

Comment: URL with an anchor to the relevant part of that page: http://api.jqueryui.com/datepicker/#utility-formatDate

Comment: The problem with datepicker (which I am currently using) is I want the input box to show dd-mm-yyyy but the value passed in the form to be yyyy-mm-dd. Don't think it can be done without manipulation.

Answer (score 243):

### Custom formatting function:

For fixed formats, a simple function make the job. Following example generate the international format YYYY-MM-DD:

```
function dateToYMD(date) {
    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    return '' + y + '-' + (m<=9 ? '0' + m : m) + '-' + (d <= 9 ? '0' + d : d);
}
```

Note: It is, however, usually not a good idea to extend the Javascript standard libraries (e.g. by adding this function to the prototype of Date).

A more advanced function could generate configurable output based on a format parameter. There are a couple of good examples in this same page.

If to write a formatting function is too long, there are plenty of libraries around which does it. Some other answers already enumerate them. But increasing dependencies also has it counter-part.

### Standard ECMAScript formatting functions:

Since more recent versions of ECMAscript, the `Date` class has some specific formatting functions:

> **toDateString**: Implementation dependent, show only the date.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.todatestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toDateString(); // e.g. "Fri Nov 11 2016"
> ```

---

> **toISOString**: Show ISO 8601 date and time.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.toisostring
>
> ```
> new Date().toISOString(); // e.g. "2016-11-21T08:00:00.000Z"
> ```

---

> **toJSON**: Stringifier for JSON.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tojson
>
> ```
> new Date().toJSON(); // e.g. "2016-11-21T08:00:00.000Z"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleDateString**: Implementation dependent, a date in locale format.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaledatestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleDateString(); // e.g. "21/11/2016"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleString**: Implementation dependent, a date&time in locale format.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocalestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleString(); // e.g. "21/11/2016, 08:00:00 AM"
> ```

---

> **toLocaleTimeString**: Implementation dependent, a time in locale format.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tolocaletimestring
>
> ```
> new Date().toLocaleTimeString(); // e.g. "08:00:00 AM"
> ```

---

> **toString**: Generic toString for Date.
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-date.prototype.tostring
>
> ```
> new Date().toString(); // e.g. "Fri Nov 11 2016 08:00:00 GMT+0100 (W. Europe Standard Time)"
> ```

Note: it is possible to generate custom output out of those formatting functions:

```
new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10); // By @Image72, return YYYY-MM-DD
```

Comment: It should be accepted answer, because it gives the required format (01-01-2000, not 1-1-2000)

Comment: new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10)
// "2015-04-27"

Comment: Would be very helpful not to have the example with 11th of September so it would be clear at which position is day and month represented.

Comment: thanks for adding the links to the source (: - see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toString

Answer (score 219):

> Where is the documentation which lists the format specifiers supported by the `Date()` object?

I stumbled across this today and was quite surprised that no one took the time to answer this simple question.  True, there are many libraries out there to help with date manipulation.  Some are better than others.  But that wasn't the question asked.

AFAIK, pure JavaScript doesn't support format specifiers **the way you have indicated you'd like to use them**.  But it does support methods for formatting dates and/or times, such as `.toLocaleDateString()`, `.toLocaleTimeString()`, and `.toUTCString()`.

The `Date` object reference I use most frequently is on the [w3schools.com website](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp) (but [a quick Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=javascript%20date%20object%20reference) will reveal many more that may better meet your needs).

Also note that the **Date Object Properties** section provides a link to [`prototype`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_prototype_date.asp), which illustrates some ways you can extend the Date object with custom methods.  There has been [some debate](http://perfectionkills.com/extending-built-in-native-objects-evil-or-not/) in the JavaScript community over the years about whether or not this is best practice, and I am not advocating for or against it, just pointing out its existence.

Comment: MDN is also a great reference: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: My answer attempted to address this question also.  I do believe that Firefox or Mozilla browsers once provided a Date.toString() method which took such a formatting string.  Unfortunately, I can find no trace of the old documentation.  It's no longer part of the standard and doesn't seem to be supported anywhere anymore, even in Firefox.

Answer (score 125):

## The Short Answer

There is no “universal” documentation that javascript caters to; every browser that has javascript is really an implementation. However, there is a standard that most modern browsers tend to follow, and that’s the EMCAScript standard; the ECMAScript standard strings would take, minimally, a modified implementation of the ISO 8601 definition.

In addition to this, there is a second standard set forward by the [IETF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet_Engineering_Task_Force) that browsers tend to follow as well, which is the definition for timestamps made in the RFC 2822. Actual documentation can be found in the references list at the bottom.

From this you can expect basic functionality, but what “ought” to be is not inherently what “is”. I’m going to go a little in depth with this procedurally though, as it appears only three people actually answered the question (Scott, goofballLogic, and peller namely) which, to me, suggests most people are unaware of what actually happens when you create a Date object.

---

## The Long Answer

> Where is the documentation which lists the format specifiers supported by the Date() object?

To answer the question, or typically even look for the answer to this question, you need to know that javascript is not a novel language; it’s actually an implementation of ECMAScript, and follows the ECMAScript standards (but note, javascript also actually pre-dated those standards; EMCAScript standards are built off the early implementation of LiveScript/JavaScript). The current ECMAScript standard is 5.1 (2011); at the time that the question was originally asked (June ’09), the standard was 3 (4 was abandoned), but 5 was released shortly after the post at the end of 2009. This should outline one problem; what standard a javascript implementation may follow, may not reflect what is actually in place, because a) it’s an implementation of a given standard, b) not all implementations of a standard are puritan, and c) functionality is not released in synchronization with a new standard as d) an implementation is a constant work in progress

Essentially, when dealing with javascript, you’re dealing with a derivative (javascript specific to the browser) of an implementation (javascript itself). Google’s V8, for example, implements ECMAScript 5.0, but Internet Explorer’s JScript doesn’t attempt to conform to any ECMAScript standard, yet Internet Explorer 9 does conform to ECMAScript 5.0.

When a single argument is passed to new Date(), it casts this function prototype:

```
new Date(value)
```

When two or more arguments are passed to new Date(), it casts this function prototype:

```
new Date (year, month [, date [, hours [, minutes [, seconds [, ms ] ] ] ] ] )
```

Both of those functions should look familiar, but this does not immediately answer your question and what quantifies as an acceptable “date format” requires further explanation. When you pass a string to new Date(), it will call the prototype (note that I'm using the word *prototype* loosely; the versions may be individual functions, or it may be part of a conditional statement in a single function) for **new Date(value)** with your string as the argument for the “value” parameter. This function will first check whether it is a number or a string. The documentation for this function can be found here:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2

From this, we can deduce that to get the string formatting allowed for new Date(value), we have to look at the method Date.parse(string). The documentation for this method can be found here:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2

And we can further infer that dates are expected to be in a modified ISO 8601 Extended Format, as specified here:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15

However, we can recognize from experience that javascript’s Date object accepts other formats (enforced by the existence of this question in the first place), and this is okay because ECMAScript allows for implementation specific formats. However, that still doesn’t answer the question of what documentation is available on the available formats, nor what formats are actually allowed. We’re going to look at Google’s javascript implementation, V8; please note I’m not suggesting this is the “best” javascript engine (how can one define “best” or even “good”) and one cannot assume that the formats allowed in V8 represent all formats available today, but I think it’s fair to assume they do follow modern expectations.

> Google’s V8, date.js, DateConstructor

> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js?r=18400#141

Looking at the DateConstructor function, we can deduce we need to find the DateParse function; however, note that “year” is not the actual year and is only a reference to the “year” parameter.

> Google’s V8, date.js, DateParse

> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js?r=18400#270

This calls %DateParseString, which is actually a run-time function reference for a C++ function. It refers to the following code:

> Google’s V8, runtime.cc, %DateParseString

> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/runtime.cc?r=18400#9559

The function call we’re concerned with in this function is for DateParser::Parse(); ignore the logic surrounding those function calls, these are just checks to conform to the encoding type (ASCII and UC16). DateParser::Parse is defined here:

> Google's V8, dateparser-inl.h, DateParser::Parse

> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/dateparser-inl.h?r=18400#36

This is the function that actually defines what formats it accepts. Essentially, it checks for the EMCAScript 5.0 ISO 8601 standard and if it is not standards compliant, then it will attempt to build the date based on legacy formats. A few key points based on the comments:

1. Words before the first number that are unknown to the parser are ignored.
2. Parenthesized text are ignored.
3. Unsigned numbers followed by “:” are interpreted as a “time component”.
4. Unsigned numbers followed by “.” are interpreted as a “time component”, and must be followed by milliseconds.
5. Signed numbers followed by the hour or hour minute (e.g. +5:15 or +0515) are interpreted as the timezone.
6. When declaring the hour and minute, you can use either “hh:mm” or “hhmm”.
7. Words that indicate a time zone are interpreted as a time zone.
8. All other numbers are interpreted as “date components”.
9. All words that start with the first three digits of a month are interpreted as the month.
10. You can define minutes and hours together in either of the two formats: “hh:mm” or “hhmm”.
11. Symbols like “+”, “-“ and unmatched “)” are not allowed after a number has been processed.
12. Items that match multiple formats (e.g. 1970-01-01) are processed as a standard compliant EMCAScript 5.0 ISO 8601 string.

So this should be enough to give you a basic idea of what to expect when it comes to passing a string into a Date object. You can further expand upon this by looking at the following specification that Mozilla points to on the Mozilla Developer Network (compliant to the IETF RFC 2822 timestamps):

> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14

The Microsoft Developer Network additionally mentions an additional standard for the Date object: ECMA-402, the ECMAScript Internationalization API Specification, which is complementary to the ECMAScript 5.1 standard (and future ones). That can be found here:

> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/

In any case, this should aid in highlighting that there is no "documentation" that universally represents all implementations of javascript, but there is still enough documentation available to make reasonable sense of what strings are acceptable for a Date object. Quite the loaded question when you think about it, yes? :P

> **References**
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.3.2
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.4.2
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.9.1.15
>
> https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2822#page-14
>
> http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-402/1.0/
>
> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js?r=18400#141
>
> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/date.js?r=18400#270
>
> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/runtime.cc?r=18400#9559
>
> https://code.google.com/p/v8/source/browse/trunk/src/dateparser-inl.h?r=18400#36
>
> **Resources**
>
> https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date
>
> http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff743760(v=vs.94).aspx

Answer (score 91):

Make sure you checkout [Datejs](http://www.datejs.com/) when dealing with dates in JavaScript. It's quite impressive and well documented as you can see in case of the [toString function](http://code.google.com/p/datejs/wiki/APIDocumentation#toString).

**EDIT**: Tyler Forsythe points out, that datejs is outdated. I use it in my current project and hadn't any trouble with it, however you should be aware of this and consider alternatives.

Comment: This is a fantastic library.  I have created a version of my own, but I have scrapped that project in favor of using this.  Thanks for the link!!!! (can you tell I am excited)

Comment: +1 for using a already existing good lib, instead of half baked solution

Comment: I couldn't find a way to feed datejs with milliseconds to create a date. Like so: var dateTime = new Date(); dateTime.setTime(milliseconds);

Comment: I can't believe such a popular library doesnt have the ability to create a date using milliseconds/seconds since the epoch.

Comment: Keep in mind, when using the cool date adding / "next thursday" type functions, always first convert to UTC, then add/subtract dates, then convert back to local time.

Comment: Here's a list of formatting strings that seem to work with Datejs: http://www.geekzilla.co.uk/View00FF7904-B510-468C-A2C8-F859AA20581F.htm I didn't test all of them, but the few that I've used worked fine.

Comment: 25k? Just for dates? Ouch.

Comment: Datejs is an outdated library that hasn't seen active development in ~5 years. Their source is on Github and Google Code and both have last updated dates of 2008 (it's 2013). For the sake of your sanity, go with XDate or Moment.js.

Comment: @TylerForsythe I added a hint / warning about that.

Comment: Another highly voted answer that doesn't answer the question.

Comment: @RobG I thought this was a case of the [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: As of September 2018, the latest commit was a723995  *on Jul 4, 2017*

Answer (score 71):

You can just expand the `Date` Object with a new `format` method as noted by [meizz](http://huahun.iteye.com/blog/197367), below is the code given by the author.  And
here is a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gongzhitaao/G5kEQ/1/).

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format) //author: meizz
{
  var o = {
    "M+" : this.getMonth()+1, //month
    "d+" : this.getDate(),    //day
    "h+" : this.getHours(),   //hour
    "m+" : this.getMinutes(), //minute
    "s+" : this.getSeconds(), //second
    "q+" : Math.floor((this.getMonth()+3)/3),  //quarter
    "S" : this.getMilliseconds() //millisecond
  }

  if(/(y+)/.test(format)) format=format.replace(RegExp.$1,
    (this.getFullYear()+"").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
  for(var k in o)if(new RegExp("("+ k +")").test(format))
    format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
      RegExp.$1.length==1 ? o[k] :
        ("00"+ o[k]).substr((""+ o[k]).length));
  return format;
}

alert(new Date().format("yyyy-MM-dd"));
alert(new Date("january 12 2008 11:12:30").format("yyyy-MM-dd h:mm:ss"));
```

Comment: Enhanced it a bit for my purposes to support AM/PM - see below

Comment: @WHK But I still like [momentjs](http://momentjs.com/) more :D

Comment: Have problem when capture month: new Date((new Date()).format('yyyy-MM-dd')) return May but now is Jun :-/ whoto use timezone in parse string?

Comment: console.log(new Date('2014-06-12')); -> Jun ||
console.log(new Date('2014-06-01')); -> May ???

Comment: @WHK This is actually a very primitive date parser.  Just in case you don't have to mess with date too much.  If you really need to cope with various formats of dates, I would recommend a standalone library like momentjs. :D

Comment: @WHK For `console.log(new Date('2014-06-01')) -> May` I think it has something to do with the timezone :D

Answer (score 36):

The functionality you cite is not standard Javascript, not likely to be portable across browsers and therefore not good practice.  The [ECMAScript 3 spec](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262.htm) leaves the parse and output formats function up to the Javascript implementation.  [ECMAScript 5](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/drafts/tc39-2009-025.pdf) adds a subset of ISO8601 support.  I believe the toString() function you mention is an innovation in one browser (Mozilla?)

Several libraries provide routines to parameterize this, some with extensive localization support.  You can also check out the methods in [dojo.date.locale](http://dojotoolkit.org/api/?qs=1.3/dojo.date.locale).

Comment: Attempting to actually answer the question won't get you many votes. Just nominate a popular library and see your score fly!!

Answer (score 31):

I made this very simple formatter, it's cut/n/pastable (Updated with neater version):

```
function DateFmt(fstr) {
  this.formatString = fstr

  var mthNames = ["Jan","Feb","Mar","Apr","May","Jun","Jul","Aug","Sep","Oct","Nov","Dec"];
  var dayNames = ["Sun","Mon","Tue","Wed","Thu","Fri","Sat"];
  var zeroPad = function(number) {
     return ("0"+number).substr(-2,2);
  }

  var dateMarkers = {
    d:['getDate',function(v) { return zeroPad(v)}],
    m:['getMonth',function(v) { return zeroPad(v+1)}],
    n:['getMonth',function(v) { return mthNames[v]; }],
    w:['getDay',function(v) { return dayNames[v]; }],
    y:['getFullYear'],
    H:['getHours',function(v) { return zeroPad(v)}],
    M:['getMinutes',function(v) { return zeroPad(v)}],
    S:['getSeconds',function(v) { return zeroPad(v)}],
    i:['toISOString']
  };

  this.format = function(date) {
    var dateTxt = this.formatString.replace(/%(.)/g, function(m, p) {
      var rv = date[(dateMarkers[p])[0]]()

      if ( dateMarkers[p][1] != null ) rv = dateMarkers[p][1](rv)

      return rv

    });

    return dateTxt
  }

}

fmt = new DateFmt("%w %d:%n:%y - %H:%M:%S  %i")
v = fmt.format(new Date())
```

http://snipplr.com/view/66968.82825/

Comment: I like this class but think it should be a "static" class. No need to instantiate it more than once.  (should not need `new DateFmt()`)

Comment: Cheeso: What if I want to format 10 different dates on a page 3 different ways, each? In that case it would be useful to have three instances of this formatter. That's a perfectly valid usecase that this would preclude. The OP designed this correctly. Also specifying a format at construction time saves code duplication of specifying a format every time you need it formatted a certain way.

Answer (score 29):

Framework free, limited but light

```
var d = (new Date()+'').split(' ');
// ["Tue", "Sep", "03", "2013", "21:54:52", "GMT-0500", "(Central", "Daylight", "Time)"]

[d[3], d[1], d[2], d[4]].join(' ');
// "2013 Sep 03 21:58:03"
```

Comment: is this cross browser? and cross locale?

Comment: Yes.  Shows time in your (browser user) local time zone.

Answer (score 21):

DateJS is certainly full-featured, but I'd recommend [this MUCH simpler lib (JavaScript Date Format)](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format) which I prefer  simply because it's only 120 lines or so.

Comment: Source code references in linked article are dead, but fortunately someone put it on Github: https://github.com/rvanbaalen/date-steroids

Answer (score 18):

Having looked through several of the options provided in other answers, I decided to write my own limited but simple solution that others may also find useful.

```
/**
* Format date as a string
* @param date - a date object (usually "new Date();")
* @param format - a string format, eg. "DD-MM-YYYY"
*/
function dateFormat(date, format) {
    // Calculate date parts and replace instances in format string accordingly
    format = format.replace("DD", (date.getDate() < 10 ? '0' : '') + date.getDate()); // Pad with '0' if needed
    format = format.replace("MM", (date.getMonth() < 9 ? '0' : '') + (date.getMonth() + 1)); // Months are zero-based
    format = format.replace("YYYY", date.getFullYear());
    return format;
}
```

Example usage:

```
console.log("The date is: " + dateFormat(new Date(), "DD/MM/YYYY"));
```

Comment: replace operations are not really efficient, so it's a better practise to prevent it.

Comment: what if I write, what is going to happen?

console.log("The date is: " + dateFormat(new Date(), "DD/MM/YY"));

Comment: This will print the text "The date is: 12/11/YY", because the above does not handle 2-digit dates. If you needed this, you could add the following immediately before the return statement:
`format = format.replace("YY", (""+date.getFullYear()).substring(2));`. This is getting ugly though - you probably want to go down the RegEx route or similar instead.

Comment: @mrzmyr Do you really think that formatting dates will be a performance bottleneck? Come on.

Answer (score 12):

Here's a function I use a lot. The result is yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss.nnn.

```
function date_and_time() {
    var date = new Date();
    //zero-pad a single zero if needed
    var zp = function (val){
        return (val <= 9 ? '0' + val : '' + val);
    }

    //zero-pad up to two zeroes if needed
    var zp2 = function(val){
        return val <= 99? (val <=9? '00' + val : '0' + val) : ('' + val ) ;
    }

    var d = date.getDate();
    var m = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var y = date.getFullYear();
    var h = date.getHours();
    var min = date.getMinutes();
    var s = date.getSeconds();
    var ms = date.getMilliseconds();
    return '' + y + '-' + zp(m) + '-' + zp(d) + ' ' + zp(h) + ':' + zp(min) + ':' + zp(s) + '.' + zp2(ms);
}
```

Comment: good answer, but I think you should change the zp2 function as: var zp2 = function(val) {
  return val <= 9 ? '00' + val : (val <= 99 ? '0' + val : '' + val);
 }

Comment: there is an exception, when the value of ms part is 0, it's not the same, in your function the result is '00', but not '000'.

Answer (score 10):

You may find useful this modification of date object, which is smaller than any library and is easily extendable to support different formats:

**NOTE:**

- It uses [Object.keys()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) which is undefined in older browsers so you may need implement polyfill from given link.

**CODE**

```
Date.prototype.format = function(format) {
    // set default format if function argument not provided
    format = format || 'YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm';

    var zeropad = function(number, length) {
            number = number.toString();
            length = length || 2;
            while(number.length < length)
                number = '0' + number;
            return number;
        },
        // here you can define your formats
        formats = {
            YYYY: this.getFullYear(),
            MM: zeropad(this.getMonth() + 1),
            DD: zeropad(this.getDate()),
            hh: zeropad(this.getHours()),
            mm: zeropad(this.getMinutes())
        },
        pattern = '(' + Object.keys(formats).join(')|(') + ')';

    return format.replace(new RegExp(pattern, 'g'), function(match) {
        return formats[match];
    });
};
```

**USE**

```
var now = new Date;
console.log(now.format());
// outputs: 2015-02-09 11:47
var yesterday = new Date('2015-02-08');
console.log(yesterday.format('hh:mm YYYY/MM/DD'));
// outputs: 00:00 2015/02/08
```

Answer (score 10):

### All browsers

The most reliable way to format a date with the source format you're using, is to apply the following steps :

1. Use `new Date()` to create a `Date` object
2. Use `.getDate()`, `.getMonth()` and `.getFullYear()` to get respectively the day, month and year
3. Paste the pieces together according to your target format

Example :

```js
var date = '2015-11-09T10:46:15.097Z';

function format(input) {
    var date = new Date(input);
    return [
       ("0" + date.getDate()).slice(-2),
       ("0" + (date.getMonth()+1)).slice(-2),
       date.getFullYear()
    ].join('/');
}

document.body.innerHTML = format(date); // OUTPUT : 09/11/2015
```

(See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/az0ab0Lm/1/)).

---

### Modern browsers only

You can also use the built-in `.toLocaleDateString` method to do the formatting for you. You just need pass along the proper locale and options to match the right format, which unfortunately is only supported by modern browsers **(*)** :

```js
var date = '2015-11-09T10:46:15.097Z';

function format(input) {
    return new Date(input).toLocaleDateString('en-GB', {
        year: 'numeric',
        month: '2-digit',
        day: '2-digit'
    });
}

document.body.innerHTML = format(date); // OUTPUT : 09/11/2015
```

(See also [**this Fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/az0ab0Lm/2/)).

---

**(*)** [**According to the MDN**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString), "Modern browsers" means Chrome 24+, Firefox 29+, IE11, Edge12+, Opera 15+ & Safari [**nightly build**](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/56490/what-does-nightly-builds-mean)

Comment: Today in 2020, it supports most browsers.

Answer (score 8):

Just to continue gongzhitaao's solid answer - this handles AM/PM

```
 Date.prototype.format = function (format) //author: meizz
{
    var hours = this.getHours();
    var ttime = "AM";
    if(format.indexOf("t") > -1 && hours > 12)
    {
        hours = hours - 12;
        ttime = "PM";
     }

var o = {
    "M+": this.getMonth() + 1, //month
    "d+": this.getDate(),    //day
    "h+": hours,   //hour
    "m+": this.getMinutes(), //minute
    "s+": this.getSeconds(), //second
    "q+": Math.floor((this.getMonth() + 3) / 3),  //quarter
    "S": this.getMilliseconds(), //millisecond,
    "t+": ttime
}

if (/(y+)/.test(format)) format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
  (this.getFullYear() + "").substr(4 - RegExp.$1.length));
for (var k in o) if (new RegExp("(" + k + ")").test(format))
    format = format.replace(RegExp.$1,
      RegExp.$1.length == 1 ? o[k] :
        ("00" + o[k]).substr(("" + o[k]).length));
return format;
}
```

Comment: Very good solution!
var a = new Date();
a.format('yyyy-MM-d'); //Return 2013-08-16.

Comment: this.getMonth(); fails in iOS

Answer (score 7):

I was unable to find any definitive documentation on valid date formats so I wrote my own test to see what is supported in various browsers.

http://blarg.co.uk/blog/javascript-date-formats

My results concluded the following formats are valid in all browsers that I tested (examples use the date "9th August 2013"):

**[Full Year]/[Month]/[Date number]** - Month can be either the number with or without a leading zero or the month name in short or long format, and date number can be with or without a leading zero.

- 2013/08/09
- 2013/08/9
- 2013/8/09
- 2013/8/9
- 2013/August/09
- 2013/August/9
- 2013/Aug/09
- 2013/Aug/9

**[Month]/[Full Year]/[Date Number]** - Month can be either the number with or without a leading zero or the month name in short or long format, and date number can be with or without a leading zero.

- 08/2013/09
- 08/2013/9
- 8/2013/09
- 8/2013/9
- August/2013/09
- August/2013/9
- Aug/2013/09
- Aug/2013/9

**Any combination of [Full Year], [Month Name] and [Date Number] separated by spaces** - Month name can be in either short or long format, and date number can be with or without a leading zero.

- 2013 August 09
- August 2013 09
- 09 August 2013
- 2013 Aug 09
- Aug 9 2013
- 2013 9 Aug
- etc...

Also valid in "modern browsers" (or in other words all browsers except IE9 and below)

**[Full Year]-[Month Number]-[Date Number]** - Month and Date Number must include leading zeros (this is the format that the [MySQL Date type](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/datetime.html) uses)

- 2013-08-09

**Using month names:**
Interestingly, when using month names I discovered that only the first 3 characters of the month name are ever used so all the of the following are perfectly valid:

```
new Date('9 August 2013');
new Date('9 Aug 2013');
new Date('9 Augu 2013');
new Date('9 Augustagfsdgsd 2013');
```

Answer (score 6):

Formatting and especially parsing dates in JavaScript can be a bit of a headache. Not all browsers handle dates in the same way. So while it's useful to know the base methods, its more practical to use a helper library.

The [XDate javascript library](http://arshaw.com/xdate/) by [Adam Shaw](https://github.com/arshaw) has been around since mid-2011 and is still under active development. It has fantastic documentation, a great API, formatting, tries to remain backwards-compatible and even supports localized strings.

Link to changing the locale strings: https://gist.github.com/1221376

Answer (score 6):

The library [sugar.js](http://sugarjs.com/) has some great functionality for working with dates in JavaScript. And it is very well [documented](http://sugarjs.com/dates).

> Sugar gives the Date class much love starting with the Date.create
>   method which can understand dates in just about any format in 15 major
>   languages, including relative formats like "1 hour ago". Dates can
>   also be output in any format or language using an easy to understand
>   syntax, with shortcuts to commonly used date formats. Complex date
>   comparison is also possible with methods like is, which understand any
>   format and apply built in precision.

A few examples:

```
Date.create('July 4, 1776')  -> July 4, 1776
Date.create(-446806800000)   -> November 5, 1955
Date.create(1776, 6, 4)      -> July 4, 1776
Date.create('1776年07月04日', 'ja') -> July 4, 1776
Date.utc.create('July 4, 1776', 'en')  -> July 4, 1776

Date.create().format('{Weekday} {d} {Month}, {yyyy}')    -> Monday July 4, 2003
Date.create().format('{hh}:{mm}')                        -> 15:57
Date.create().format('{12hr}:{mm}{tt}')                  -> 3:57pm
Date.create().format(Date.ISO8601_DATETIME)              -> 2011-07-05 12:24:55.528Z

Date.create().is('the 7th of June') -> false
Date.create().addMonths(2); ->"Sunday, June 15, 2014 13:39"
```

Answer (score 6):

Example code:

```
var d = new Date();
var time = d.toISOString().replace(/.*?T(\d+:\d+:\d+).*/, "$1");
```

Output:

> "13:45:20"

Comment: worth noting with toISOString(); it outputs UTC. So if `new Date();// = Fri Nov 22 2013 17:48:22 GMT+0100`, the output with the above code will be `"16:48:22"`

Answer (score 3):

Just another option, which I wrote:

[DP_DateExtensions Library](http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/)

Not sure if it'll help, but I've found it useful in several projects - looks like it'll do what you need.

Supports date/time formatting, date math (add/subtract date parts), date compare, date parsing, etc. It's liberally open sourced.

No reason to consider it if you're already using a framework (they're all capable), but if you just need to quickly add date manipulation to a project give it a chance.

Comment: I guess the new URL is http://depressedpress.com/javascript-extensions/dp_dateextensions/

Answer (score 2):

If you want to show only time with **two** digits, this may helps you:

```
var now = new Date();
var cHour = now.getHours();
var cMinuts = now.getMinutes();
var cSeconds = now.getSeconds();

var outStr = (cHour <= 0 ? ('0' + cHour) : cHour) + ':' + (cMinuts <= 9 ? ('0' + cMinuts) : cMinuts) + ':' + (cSeconds <= 9 ? '0' + cSeconds : cSeconds);
```

Answer (score 2):

use this functions

```
toTimeString() and toLocaleDateString()
```

refer below link for more details
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Answer (score 2):

Almost all the modern browsers now support [`toLocaleString(locales, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString) & [`toLocaleDateString(locales, options)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleDateString) where `options` is an optional parameter to sepcify the format.

Example:

```js
const event = new Date(Date.UTC(2012, 11, 20, 3, 0, 0));
const options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };

console.log(event.toLocaleDateString(undefined, options));
// expected output: Thursday, December 20, 2012 (varies according to default locale)
```

And according to [tc39.es/ecma402](https://tc39.es/ecma402/#table-datetimeformat-components) and [w3c.org](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_tolocalestring.asp), following are the supported list of parameter values :

### locales:

`ar-SA`, `bn-BD`, `bn-IN`, `cs-CZ`, `da-DK`, `de-AT`, `de-CH`, `de-DE`, `el-GR`, `en-AU`, `en-CA`, `en-GB`, `en-IE`, `en-IN`, `en-NZ`, `en-US`, `en-ZA`, `es-AR`, `es-CL`, `es-CO`, `es-ES`, `es-MX`, `es-US`, `fi-FI`, `fr-BE`, `fr-CA`, `fr-CH`, `fr-FR`, `he-IL`, `hi-IN`, `hu-HU`, `id-ID`, `it-CH`, `it-IT`, `ja-JP`, `ko-KR`, `nl-BE`, `nl-NL`, `no-NO`, `pl-PL`, `pt-BR`, `pt-PT`, `ro-RO`, `ru-RU`, `sk-SK`, `sv-SE`, `ta-IN`, `ta-LK`, `th-TH`, `tr-TR`, `zh-CN`, `zh-HK`, `zh-TW`

### options:

| Internal Slot | Property | Values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| [[Weekday]] | "weekday" | "narrow", "short", "long" |
| [[Era]] | "era" | "narrow", "short", "long" |
| [[Year]] | "year" | "2-digit", "numeric" |
| [[Month]] | "month" | "2-digit", "numeric", "narrow", "short", "long" |
| [[Day]] | "day" | "2-digit", "numeric" |
| [[DayPeriod]] | "dayPeriod" | "narrow", "short", "long" |
| [[Hour]] | "hour" | "2-digit", "numeric" |
| [[Minute]] | "minute" | "2-digit", "numeric" |
| [[Second]] | "second" | "2-digit", "numeric" |
| [[FractionalSecondDigits]] | "fractionalSecondDigits" | 1, 2, 3 |
| [[TimeZoneName]] | "timeZoneName" | "short", "long" |

Answer (score 1):

[JsSimpleDateFormat](http://www.javascriptsource.com/repository/javascripts/2009/03/880961/JS_Simple_Date_Format.zip) is a library that can format the date object and parse the formatted string back to Date object. It uses the Java format (SimpleDateFormat class). The name of months and days can be localized.

Example:

```
var sdf = new JsSimpleDateFormat("EEEE, MMMM dd, yyyy");
var formattedString = sdf.format(new Date());
var dateObject = sdf.parse("Monday, June 29, 2009");
```

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "nowhere" since the date formatting is proprietary functionality. I don't think the toString functions are intended to conform to a specific format. e.g. in the ECMAScript 5.1 spec (http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/files/ECMA-ST/Ecma-262.pdf, 2/8/2013, page 173), the *toString* function is documented as follows:

> "The contents of the String are implementation-dependent"

Functions such as the samples below could be used to accomplish formatting fairly easily.

```
function pad(toPad, padWith) {
    return (String(padWith) + String(toPad)).slice(-1 * padWith.length);
}

function dateAsInputValue(toFormat) {
    if(!(toFormat instanceof Date)) return null;
    return toFormat.getFullYear() + "-" + pad(toFormat.getMonth() + 1, "00") + "-" + pad(toFormat.getDate(), "00");
}

function timeAsInputValue(toFormat) {
    if(!(toFormat instanceof Date)) return null;        
    return pad(toFormat.getHours(), "00") + ":" + pad(toFormat.getMinutes(), "00") + ":" + pad(toFormat.getSeconds(), "00");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't need all the features that a library like [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) provides, then you can use my port of [strftime](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html). It's lightweight (1.35 KB vs. 57.9 KB minified compared to Moment.js 2.15.0) and provides most of the functionality of `strftime()`.

```
/* Port of strftime(). Compatibility notes:
 *
 * %c - formatted string is slightly different
 * %D - not implemented (use "%m/%d/%y" or "%d/%m/%y")
 * %e - space is not added
 * %E - not implemented
 * %h - not implemented (use "%b")
 * %k - space is not added
 * %n - not implemented (use "\n")
 * %O - not implemented
 * %r - not implemented (use "%I:%M:%S %p")
 * %R - not implemented (use "%H:%M")
 * %t - not implemented (use "\t")
 * %T - not implemented (use "%H:%M:%S")
 * %U - not implemented
 * %W - not implemented
 * %+ - not implemented
 * %% - not implemented (use "%")
 *
 * strftime() reference:
 * http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html
 *
 * Day of year (%j) code based on Joe Orost's answer:
 * http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8619879/javascript-calculate-the-day-of-the-year-1-366
 *
 * Week number (%V) code based on Taco van den Broek's prototype:
 * http://techblog.procurios.nl/k/news/view/33796/14863/calculate-iso-8601-week-and-year-in-javascript.html
 */
function strftime(sFormat, date) {
  if (!(date instanceof Date)) date = new Date();
  var nDay = date.getDay(),
    nDate = date.getDate(),
    nMonth = date.getMonth(),
    nYear = date.getFullYear(),
    nHour = date.getHours(),
    aDays = ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday'],
    aMonths = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'],
    aDayCount = [0, 31, 59, 90, 120, 151, 181, 212, 243, 273, 304, 334],
    isLeapYear = function() {
      if (nYear&3!==0) return false;
      return nYear%100!==0 || year%400===0;
    },
    getThursday = function() {
      var target = new Date(date);
      target.setDate(nDate - ((nDay+6)%7) + 3);
      return target;
    },
    zeroPad = function(nNum, nPad) {
      return ('' + (Math.pow(10, nPad) + nNum)).slice(1);
    };
  return sFormat.replace(/%[a-z]/gi, function(sMatch) {
    return {
      '%a': aDays[nDay].slice(0,3),
      '%A': aDays[nDay],
      '%b': aMonths[nMonth].slice(0,3),
      '%B': aMonths[nMonth],
      '%c': date.toUTCString(),
      '%C': Math.floor(nYear/100),
      '%d': zeroPad(nDate, 2),
      '%e': nDate,
      '%F': date.toISOString().slice(0,10),
      '%G': getThursday().getFullYear(),
      '%g': ('' + getThursday().getFullYear()).slice(2),
      '%H': zeroPad(nHour, 2),
      '%I': zeroPad((nHour+11)%12 + 1, 2),
      '%j': zeroPad(aDayCount[nMonth] + nDate + ((nMonth>1 && isLeapYear()) ? 1 : 0), 3),
      '%k': '' + nHour,
      '%l': (nHour+11)%12 + 1,
      '%m': zeroPad(nMonth + 1, 2),
      '%M': zeroPad(date.getMinutes(), 2),
      '%p': (nHour<12) ? 'AM' : 'PM',
      '%P': (nHour<12) ? 'am' : 'pm',
      '%s': Math.round(date.getTime()/1000),
      '%S': zeroPad(date.getSeconds(), 2),
      '%u': nDay || 7,
      '%V': (function() {
              var target = getThursday(),
                n1stThu = target.valueOf();
              target.setMonth(0, 1);
              var nJan1 = target.getDay();
              if (nJan1!==4) target.setMonth(0, 1 + ((4-nJan1)+7)%7);
              return zeroPad(1 + Math.ceil((n1stThu-target)/604800000), 2);
            })(),
      '%w': '' + nDay,
      '%x': date.toLocaleDateString(),
      '%X': date.toLocaleTimeString(),
      '%y': ('' + nYear).slice(2),
      '%Y': nYear,
      '%z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+GMT([+-]\d+).+/, '$1'),
      '%Z': date.toTimeString().replace(/.+\((.+?)\)$/, '$1')
    }[sMatch] || sMatch;
  });
}
```

**Sample usage:**

```
strftime('%F'); // Returns "2016-09-15"
strftime('%A, %B %e, %Y'); // Returns "Thursday, September 15, 2016"

// You can optionally pass it a Date object...

strftime('%x %X', new Date('1/1/2016')); // Returns "1/1/2016 12:00:00 AM"
```

The latest code is available here: https://github.com/thdoan/strftime

Answer (score 1):

the lazy solution is to use `Date.toLocaleString` with the right region code

to get a list of matching regions you can run

```sh
#!/bin/bash

[ -f bcp47.json ] || \
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/pculture/bcp47-json/master/bcp47.json

grep 'tag" : ' bcp47.json | cut -d'"' -f4 >codes.txt

js=$(cat <<'EOF'
const fs = require('fs');
const d = new Date(2020, 11, 12, 20, 00, 00);
fs.readFileSync('codes.txt', 'utf8')
.split('\n')
.forEach(code => {
  try {
    console.log(code+' '+d.toLocaleString(code))
  }
  catch (e) { console.log(code+' '+e.message) }
});
EOF
)

# print THE LIST of civilized countries
echo "$js" | node - | grep '2020-12-12 20:00:00'
```

and here is .... THE LIST

```
af ce eo gv ha ku kw ky lt mg rw se sn sv xh zu 
ksh mgo sah wae AF KW KY LT MG RW SE SN SV
```

sample use:

```js
(new Date()).toLocaleString('af')

// -> '2020-12-21 11:50:15'
```

: )

(note. this MAY not be portable.)

Answer (score 1):

[date-fns](https://date-fns.org/) is the latest and greatest contender (better than momentjs at this moment). Some of the advantages are

- Modular
- Immutable
- I18n
- Tree-shaking
- Typescript support

Refer here for documentation

And you'd do something like this:

```
import { format, formatDistance, formatRelative, subDays } from 'date-fns'

format(new Date(), "'Today is a' eeee")
//=> "Today is a Tuesday"

formatDistance(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date(), { addSuffix: true })
//=> "3 days ago"

formatRelative(subDays(new Date(), 3), new Date())
//=> "last Friday at 7:26 p.m."
```

Answer (score 0):

The correct way to format a date to return "2012-12-29" is with the script from *[JavaScript Date Format](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/date-time-format)*:

```
var d1 = new Date();
return d1.format("dd-m-yy");
```

This code does NOT work:

```
var d1 = new Date();
d1.toString('yyyy-MM-dd');
```

Comment: you need the script linked "JavaScript Date Format" linked above

Answer (score 0):

Personally, because I use both PHP and jQuery/javascript in equal measures, I use the date function from php.js http://phpjs.org/functions/date/

Using a library that uses the same format strings as something I already know is easier for me, and the manual containing all of the format string possibilities for the date function is of course online at php.net

You simply include the date.js file in your HTML using your preferred method then call it like this:

```
var d1=new Date();
var datestring = date('Y-m-d', d1.valueOf()/1000);
```

You can use d1.getTime() instead of valueOf() if you want, they do the same thing.

The divide by 1000 of the javascript timestamp is because a javascript timestamp is in miliseconds but a PHP timestamp is in seconds.

Answer (score 0):

Many frameworks (that you might already be using) have date formatting that you may not be aware of.  jQueryUI  was already mentioned, but other frameworks such as [Kendo UI (Globalization)](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/framework/globalization/dateformatting), [Yahoo UI (Util)](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/docs/YAHOO.util.Date.html) and [AngularJS](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.filter%3adate) have them as well.

```
// 11/6/2000
kendo.toString(new Date(value), "d")

// Monday, November 06, 2000
kendo.toString(new Date(2000, 10, 6), "D")
```

Answer (score 0):

See [dtmFRM.js](https://rawgithub.com/minagabriel/dtmFRM/master/dtmFRM.js). If you are familiar with C#'s custom date and time format string, this library should do the exact same thing.

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/minagabriel/7sN5k/):

```
var format = new dtmFRM();
var now = new Date().getTime();

$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"This month is : MMMM") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"Year is  : y or yyyy or yy") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"mm/yyyy/dd") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"dddd, MM yyyy ") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"Time is : hh:mm:ss ampm") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"HH:mm") + "</br>");
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"[ddd,MMM,d,dddd]") + "</br></br>");

now = '11/11/2011 10:15:12' ;

$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss ampm") + "</br></br>");

now = '40/23/2012'
$('#s2').append(format.ToString(now,"Year is  : y or yyyy or yy") + "</br></br>");
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
d = Date.now();
d = new Date(d);
d = (d.getMonth()+1)+'/'+d.getDate()+'/'+d.getFullYear()+' '+(d.getHours() > 12 ? d.getHours() - 12 : d.getHours())+':'+d.getMinutes()+' '+(d.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM");

console.log(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

For curious folks, there is an experimental feature called [tc39/temporal](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/index.html) which is currently at stage 3 proposal that brings a modern date/time API to the ECMAScript language.

Quoting the tc39 website:

> `Date` has been a long-standing pain point in ECMAScript. This is a proposal for `Temporal`, a global `Object` that acts as a top-level namespace (like `Math`), that brings a modern date/time API to the ECMAScript language. For a detailed look at some of the problems with `Date`, and the motivations for Temporal, see: [Fixing JavaScript Date](https://maggiepint.com/2017/04/09/fixing-javascript-date-getting-started/).

> A cookbook to help you get started and learn the ins and outs of Temporal is available [here](https://tc39.es/proposal-temporal/docs/cookbook.html).

### Additional Resources:

- GitHub Repository - [tc39/proposal-temporal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-temporal)
- There's also a [YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyccvgiCo1c) which talks about this proposal in detail.

  - This article gives a brief overview of the above video - [Learn how JavaScript advances DateTime with proposal-temporal](https://dev.to/github/learn-how-the-javascript-advances-datetime-with-proposal-temporal-59hf)
- [How to Outsmart Time: Building Futuristic JavaScript Apps Using Temporal](https://portal.gitnation.org/contents/how-to-outsmart-time-building-futuristic-javascript-apps-using-temporal)

Answer (score 0):

Extract each part from the date and use string functions (e.g. [`String.padStart`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/padStart)) to format.

The following example formats the date object as [the simplified ISO 8601 format](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/numbers-and-dates.html#sec-date-time-string-format):

```js
function formatDate(date) {
  let datePart = [
    date.getFullYear(),
    date.getMonth() + 1,
    date.getDate()
  ].map((n, i) => n.toString().padStart(i === 0 ? 4 : 2, "0")).join("-");
  let timePart = [
    date.getHours(),
    date.getMinutes(),
    date.getSeconds()
  ].map((n, i) => n.toString().padStart(2, "0")).join(":");
  return datePart + "T" + timePart;
}

let dates = [
  new Date(),
  new Date("2024-01-15T12:00:00"),
  new Date("2024-01-15T12:00:00Z"),
];
dates.forEach((date) => {
  console.log("%o => %s", date, formatDate(date));
});
```

Answer (score -1):

Although JavaScript gives you many great ways of formatting and calculations, I prefer using the Moment.js (momentjs.com) library during application development as it's very intuitive and saves a lot of time.

Nonetheless, I suggest everyone to learn about the basic JavaScript API too for a better understanding.

Comment: It's also incredibly bloated.

Answer (score -1):

We can do it manually, its pretty straight and simple.

```js
var today = new Date();
    
    alert("today :"+today);
    
    var dd = today.getDate();
    alert("dd :"+dd);
    
    var mm = today.getMonth()+1; //January is 0!
    alert("mm :"+mm);
    
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    
    alert("yyyy :"+yyyy);
    
    
    var hh = today.getHours();
    
    alert("hh :"+hh);
    
    var min = today.getMinutes();
    
   alert("min :"+min);
   
   var ss = today.getSeconds();
   
   alert("ss :"+ss);

    if(dd<10) {
        dd='0'+dd
    } 

    if(mm<10) {
        mm='0'+mm
    } 

  //  today = mm+'/'+dd+'/'+yyyy;
    // if you want / instead - then add /
  
  
  today = yyyy + "-" + mm + "-" + dd + " " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
     today = yyyy + "/" + mm + "/" + dd + " " + hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;
     // use according to your choice
```

Comment: Just a small comment it's not 'hh + ":" + mm + ":" + ss;' but 'hh + ":" + min + ":" + ss;' :)

Answer (score -1):

### The specific answer to this question is found in these two lines below:

```js
//pull the last two digits of the year
console.log(new Date().getFullYear().toString().substr(2,2));
```

### Formatting Full Date Time Example (MMddyy): [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abc123/2zCkR/)

**JavaScript:**

```js
    //A function for formatting a date to MMddyy
function formatDate(d)
{
    //get the month
    var month = d.getMonth();
    //get the day
    var day = d.getDate();
    //get the year
    var year = d.getFullYear();
    
    //pull the last two digits of the year
    year = year.toString().substr(2,2);
    
    //increment month by 1 since it is 0 indexed
    month = month + 1;
    //converts month to a string
    month = month + "";

    //if month is 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (month.length == 1)
    {
        month = "0" + month;
    }

    //convert day to string
    day = day + "";

    //if day is between 1-9 pad right with a 0 for two digits
    if (day.length == 1)
    {
        day = "0" + day;
    }

    //return the string "MMddyy"
    return month + day + year;
}

var d = new Date();
console.log(formatDate(d));
```